# Events disappear after deploying the cloud function in [appwrite console]

Tags: function, events, cloud, appwrite

I have created a database on appwrite console to which I have added a function and gave data base id and collection id in the Events section in the bottom, after I have deployed it on the vs code the collection id and database id disappear from the events,for which I have to add them back every single time before I deploy any category for that function.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have your events defined in your appwrite.json file? For example, for my Appwrite version 0.15.3, my appwrite.json has this Appwrite Function:

```json
{
    "$id": "process-photo",
    "name": "process-photo",
    "runtime": "node-16.0",
    "path": "appwrite-functions/process-photo",
    "entrypoint": "src/index.js",
    "vars": {
        "APPWRITE_FUNCTION_ENDPOINT": "",
        "APPWRITE_FUNCTION_API_KEY": ""
    },
    "execute": [],
    "events": [
        "buckets.*.files.*.create"
    ],
    "schedule": "",
    "timeout": 15
}
```

Comment: I really want to thank you for your help Steven , that was really helpful.i haven't defined it in the appwrite.json folder,I'm a fresher in this field.